# Appending Form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I want to use a button to create a form that ask user input and send it to php file without refreshing, but after i append the form to the html file and tried to submit it, the java function didnt run.

The function that i used to append the form:

```
function reporterror(){
if (document.getElementById("report")){
    console.log("Still have report");
}else{
     $("<form id='report' action='report.php' method='post'><div ><h2 style='text-align:center;'>Report Error</h2><h3>Description:</h3><textarea rows='10' cols='60' name='report' id='description' placeholder='No more than 500 words' style='border-radius:10px;border:1px solid #000;'></textarea><input type='submit' style='border-radius:5px;'></input><input type='button' onclick='reportclose()' value='Close' style='border-radius:5px;'></input></div></form>").appendTo("#content"); 
}
```

};

The function that didnt run:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#report").on("submit",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (document.getElementById("description").value==""){
        $(".warning").remove();
        $("#description").after("<p class='warning' style='color:red'>Description is required</p>");
        console.log("yes");
    }else{

        $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"report.php",
                 data:$("#report").serialize(),
                 success:function(){
                    console.log("Great");
                    document.getElementById("report").innerHTML="<h2>Thank You for helping us to improve!</h2><br><p>Your message have been successfully sented to this awesome website!</p><input type='button' onclick='reportclose()' value='Close' style='border-radius:5px;'></input>";
                 }
        })

   }
});
```

})

this is what it look like right now : http://cs20p.site11.com/

Comment: I guess you need to delegate onsubmit event: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/  BUT how do you call `reporterror()` method???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change this line `$("#report").on("submit",function(event){`

to `$(document).on("submit", ".report", function(event){`

and this `$("<form id='report'` 
to `$("<form class='report' id='report'`

Problem appears because you used id instead of class. Id element can be only one

Comment: Problem appears because you used id instead of class. Id element can be only one